# python: dictionaries of lists are somehow coupled

Tags: python, variables, dictionary

I wrote a small python program to iterate over data file (*input_file*) and perform calculations. If calculation result reaches certain states (*stateA* or *stateB*), information (*hits*) are extracted from the results. The hits to extract depend on parameters from three parameter sets.
I used a dictionary of dictionaries to store my parameter sets (*param_sets*) and a dictionary of lists to store the hits (*hits*). The dictionaries *param_sets* and *hits* have the same keys.

The problem is,

that the lists within the *hits* dictionary are somehow coupled. When one list changes (by calling *extract_hits* function), the others change, too.

Here, the (shortened) code:

```
import os, sys, csv, pdb
from operator import itemgetter

# define three parameter sets
param_sets = {
    'A' : {'MIN_LEN' : 8, 'MAX_X' : 0, 'MAX_Z' : 0},
    'B' : {'MIN_LEN' : 8, 'MAX_X' : 1, 'MAX_Z' : 5},
    'C' : {'MIN_LEN' : 9, 'MAX_X' : 1, 'MAX_Z' : 5}}

# to store hits corresponding to each parameter set
hits = dict.fromkeys(param_sets, [])

# calculations
result = []
for input_values in input_file:
    # do some calculations
    result = do_some_calculations(result, input_values)
    if result == stateA:
        for key in param_sets.keys():
            hits[key] = extract_hits(key, result,
                                                hits[key],
                                                param_sets[key]['MIN_LEN'],
                                                param_sets[key]['MAX_X'],
                                                param_sets[key]['MAX_Z'])
        result = []  # discard results, start empty result list
    elif result == stateB:
        for key in param_sets.keys():
            local_heli[key] = extract_hits(key,
                                           result,
                                           hits[key],
                                           param_sets[key]['MIN_LEN'],
                                           param_sets[key]['MAX_X'],
                                           param_sets[key]['MAX_Z'])
        result = [] # discard results
        result = some_calculation(input_values) # start new result list
    else:
        result = some_other_calculation(result) # append result list



def extract_hits(k, seq, hits, min_len, max_au, max_gu):
    max_len = len(seq)
    for sub_seq_size in reversed(range(min_len, max_len+1)):
        for start_pos in range(0,(max_len-sub_seq_size+1)):
            from_inc = start_pos
            to_exc = start_pos + sub_seq_size
            sub_seq = seq[from_inc:to_exc]
            # complete information about helical fragment sub_seq
            helical_fragment = get_helix_data(sub_seq, max_au, max_gu)
            if helical_fragment:
                hits.append(helical_fragment)
                # search seq regions left and right from sub_seq for further hits
                left_seq = seq[0:from_inc]
                right_seq = seq[to_exc:max_len]
                if len(left_seq) >= min_len:
                    hits = sub_check_helical(left_seq, hits, min_len, max_au, max_gu)
                if len(right_seq) >= min_len:
                    hits = sub_check_helical(right_seq, hits, min_len, max_au, max_gu)
                print 'key', k                 # just for testing purpose
                print 'new', hits              # just for testing purpose
                print 'frag', helical_fragment # just for testing purpose
                pdb.set_trace()                # just for testing purpose
                return hits # appended
    return hits # unchanged
```

here, some output from the python debugger:

```
key A
new ['x', 'x', 'x', {'y': 'GGCCGGGCUUGGU'}]
frag {'y': 'GGCCGGGCUUGGU'}
> 
-> return hits
(Pdb) c
key B

new [{'y': 'GGCCGGGCUUGGU'}, {'y': 'CCGGCCCGAGCCG'}]
frag {'y': 'CCGGCCCGAGCCG'}
> extract_hits()
-> return hits
(Pdb) c
key C
new [{'y': 'GGCCGGGCUUGGU'}, {'y': 'CCGGCCCGAGCCG'}, {'y': 'CCGGCCCG'}]
frag {'y': 'CCGGCCCG'}
> extract_hits()
-> return hits
```

the elements from *key A* should not be present in *key B* and elements from key A and key B should not be present in *key C*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your line:

```
hits = dict.fromkeys(param_sets, [])
```

is equivalent to:

```
hits = dict()
onelist = []
for k in param_sets:
    hits[k] = onelist
```

That is, every entry in `hits` has as its value the SAME list object, initially empty, no matter what key it has. Remember that assignment does NOT perform implicit copies: rather, it assigns "one more reference to the RHS object".

What you want is:

```
hits = dict()
for k in param_sets:
    hits[k] = []
```

that is, a NEW AND SEPARATE list object as each entry's value.  Equivalently,

```
hits = dict((k, []) for k in param_sets)
```

BTW, when you *do* need to make a (shallow) copy of a container, the most general approach is generally to call the container's type, with the old container as the argument, as in:

```
newdict = dict(olddict)
newlist = list(oldlist)
newset = set(oldset)
```

and so forth; this also work to transform containers among types (`newlist = list(oldset)` makes a list out of a set, and so on).

Comment: @Simon, always glad to help, though it does seem very weird indeed to set "community wiki" for such an exquisitely technical question -- why ever did you do THAT?!

Answer (score 4):

Dictionaries and lists are passed around by reference by default.  For a dictionary, instead of:

```
hits_old = hits      # just for testing purpose
```

it would be:

```
hits_old = hits.copy()      # just for testing purpose
```

This will copy the dictionary's key/value pairings, resulting in an equivalent dictionary, that would not contain future changes to the hits dictionary.

Of course, hits_old in the second function is actually a list, not a dictionary, so you would want to do something akin to the following to copy it:

```
hits_old = hits[:]
```

I haven't a clue why lists don't also have the copy() function, in case you're wondering.

Comment: thanks, this owrks out.

Still, I wonder why the list elements from key 'A' are copied into the list stored at key 'B' within the global hits dictionary. Maybe, I am just blind for the obvious but I really can't figure out.

Comment: I think it's because of how python passes objects by reference and how you're handling the keys there. Here's a link testingreflections.com/node/view/5126 and here's another one right from the horses mouth... docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html

Comment: An alternative to .copy or [:] is to just create a new list, passing the old list to the constructor.  ie `newlist = list(other_list)` or `new_dict = dict(other_dict)`

Comment: thanks, guys! I really though python would pass by value.

All problems solved - and I guess, I learned some essential stuff.